# Wipe SVN to reinitialise

Tags: svn, restart

Does anybody know how to delete the complete svn repository including old revisions? I just want to start again ;)

Thanks,
wishi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have stated, to remove a complete repository remove the folder that contains it.

This seems a bit to straightforward though which makes me think that maybe you want to do that without access to the filesystem on the server where the repository is hosted? If thats the case, what you want to do cant be done.

SVN are working on a new *obliterate* command (which removes entire revisions as Ive understood it) that might be able to do something close to what you want. But that command isnt in the stable releases yet.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you use linux and the repository (not the workspace) lies in `/home/svn/repo`

```
rm -rf /home/svn/repo
```

Basically just delete the folder which holds the actual repository files.

Answer (score 1):

just create a new repository and delete the old one.

Comment: Just to make sure - you want to delete the repository and not the local copy... right ?!

Answer (score 1):

Just delete your svn repos dir and roll a new one. You might want to export your source tree beforehand. If you forget this, just delete every .svn directory inside your current checkout.